# Displaying code blocks within quotes

Tags: discussion, code-block, blockquote

Please see this answer: [Javascript Function toString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996843/javascript-function-tostring/18996906#18996906)

The response is quoting from http://shamansir.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/en/#object, which has some text segments and some code segments.  What is the appropriate way to denote a code block within a quote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is already rather ok, depending on the amount of code. It doesn't look too bad.

> Some description

```c
while (stuff) { doit(); }
```

> More stuff

The other option is to put a code block inside the quotes, which requires five spaces after the `>`:

> Some description
>
> ```c
> while (stuff) { doit(); }
> ```
>
> More stuff